# GFP mask of 0x200da on a 64-bit system?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, memory-management

Recently, an OOM showed a GFP mask of 0x200da on a 64-bit system. How is that possible?

`0xa` would suggest we are talking about Movable Highmem, see: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/gfp.h

```
14 #define ___GFP_HIGHMEM          0x02u
16 #define ___GFP_MOVABLE          0x08u
```

However, there is Normal, DMA, and DMA32 zones on a 64-bit system, no HIGHMEM.

(This is a 3.0.101 x86_64 kernel of SLES11SP3.)